# has_one association with chaining include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a Company, CompanyUser, User and Rating model defined like this:

**Company model**

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :users, through: :company_users


  has_one :company_owner, where(is_owner: true), class_name: 'CompanyUser', foreign_key: :user_id
  has_one :owner, through: :company_owner
end
```

There is an `is_owner` flag in the `company_users` table to identify the owner of the company.

**CompanyUser model**

```
class CompanyUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :company_users
  has_many :companies, through: :company_users

  has_many :ratings
end
```

**Rating model**

```
class Rating
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job
end
```

I am able to find the owner of a company, by the following code:

```
@owner = @company.owner
```

I need to get the ratings and the jobs of the owner along with the owner. I can do this

```
@owner = @company.owner
@ratings = @owner.ratings.includes(:job)
```

But we have already used `@owner.ratings` at many places in the view, and it is difficult to change all the references in the views as it is a pretty big view spanning in several partials. I tried the following to get the ratings along with the owner

```
@owner = @company.owner.includes(:ratings => :job)
```

But this gives me error as `@company.owner` seems to give a `User` object and it does not seem to support chaining.

Is there a way I can get the included associations (`ratings` and `job`) inside the `@owner` object?

Comment: Do you want eager loading of ratings and job data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with:

```
@owner = Company.where(id: @company.id).includes(owner: {ratings: :job}).owner
```

However this is not very clean. Much better would be to actually change `@company` variable:

```
@company = Company.includes(owner: {ratings: :job}).find(params[:company_id])  # or params id or any other call you're currently using to get the company.
```

Company built that way will already have everything included, so:

```
@owner = @company.owner
```

will pass a model with preloaded associations.

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to think that way. Definitely changing the `@company` to include `owner `, `ratings` and `job` will work. That is a brilliant idea.